# Why should I use a class or an id on a <body> tag?

Tags: html, css, tags

I see a lot of people giving the HTML `<body>`-tag an id or a class to access it via CSS. Why would I do this, when I am able to access it directly as tag itself?

**Why would I do this?**

Example 1:

```
.body-wrapper {
   margin: 0px 3px;
}
```

**Instead of this?**

Example 2:

```
body {
   margin: 0px 3px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the deleted comments. Stupid iframes. I'm thinking it's in case you want to include the CSS on tons of files, and only want certain styles applied to the body of certain pages, and not to others. That way you can include the same CSS to every page, and just denote which bodies you want to display as `.body-wrapper` class elements...

Comment: @mark.hch That makes sense. Alright, so there are no CSS tricks you can only do with `classes`/`id`'s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's useful if you want to have as few stylesheets as possible (like, say, *one*), but still want to customize the display of certain pages.

This can be useful:

- If you want to change the background for one of your webpages.
- If you want to dynamically change the theme of your site (like http://lisperator.net/ does, though it's on the `<html>` tag)
- Do something nifty with JavaScript to transform the webpage (see previous list item)
- It's CSS. You can do what you want with it!

More about this on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/id-your-body-for-greater-css-control-and-specificity/).

---

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Type `<body`.

Wonder of wonders! StackOverflow uses `<body>` classes!

NOTE: SO doesn't style them directly with CSS, but rather uses them as handles for JS

Answer (score 3):

Consider these two scenarios:

- You have anchor elements throughout your page. Each of these anchor elements takes the user to the top of the page, like so:

  ```
  <a href="#top-of-page">Go to top</a>
  ```

  Well, the top of the page could be this: `<body id="top-of-page">`
- What if you want certain elements to have similar styling, such as a border.

  ```
  .frame-this { border: 2px dashed black; }
  ```

  If you want the `body` element to have this border, it would take this class:

  ```
   <body class="frame-this"> ... </body>
  ```

These are somewhat far-fetched scenarios, but they illustrate two reasons where the `body` element might need an `id` or a `class`.

See also this article on CSS-Tricks: [**Why use Classes or IDs on the HTML element?**](https://css-tricks.com/why-use-classes-or-ids-on-the-html-element/)

Comment: Thank your really much for the answer.